# Exclude dependencies by repository

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is there a way to tell Gradle to exclude all dependencies of a particular dependency, that would be pulled from a given repository ?

Removing that repository from the repositories list would not work, because I need that repository for other dependencies. But for one particular group, I want to exclude all dependencies that would come from that repository.

Something like :

```
dependencies {
    compile <my_first_package>
    compile('my_second_package') {
        exclude repository.name:thirdPartyRepository
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, there are only two possibilities how to exclude a dependency and that is to [exclude by module or a group](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/f001402c8b7f404c923d972f1bc524b2de7b3fcd/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ExcludeRule.java). You can also mark a dependency not to fetch its transitive dependencies:

```
compile('my_second_package') {
    transitive = false
}
```

But that's all, there seems to be no way to remove dependencies based on repository. You can force versions using a [ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html), maybe take a look if something there helps your use case.

As a workaround, maybe you can repackage the wrong dependency under a different name or version. Or you could use the `transitive = false` and simply add all the transitive dependencies that you actually want as declared dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your research. I guess another workaround could be to define a repository only for a given dependency. Do you know if that is possible ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.